# Saving a dataframe to xlsx with left alignment

Tags: python, excel, pandas

When saving a Pandas Dataframe to disk as an `xlsx` file, is there any way to save it so that columns holding strings are saved with left alignment, instead of the default "center" alignment?

I am currently using the following to save my DataFRame

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path_to_file)
df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it isn't currently possible to apply Excel formatting when writing data with Pandas `to_excel()`.

You can apply column formatting when using XlsxWriter as the Excel writer engine. See [Working with Python Pandas and XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_pandas.html).